# Python Dash Basic Auth - get username in app

Tags: python, authentication, web-applications, callback, plotly-dash

I am currently making a Dash app which would show different layout based on user privilege, so I would like to be able to identify the user which is signed up. I'm using Basic Auth and I changed some lines in dash_auth/basic_auth.py:
Original:

```
username_password_utf8 = username_password.decode('utf-8')
username, password = username_password_utf8.split(':')
```

to:

```
username_password_utf8 = username_password.decode('utf-8')
username, password = username_password_utf8.split(':')
self._username = username
```

Unfortunately, I received the : AttributeError: 'BasicAuth' object has no attribute '_username' error when I tried to use the _username attribute from auth.

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.H3("Hello " + auth._username)
)
```

I understand that the Dash app is already processed before authorization check, but I have no idea where to implement a callback that changes the layout according to username. How can I get the username in the Dash application?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, you can use flask.request to access the authorization information.

Here's a minimal working example based on the [dash authentication documentation](https://dash.plot.ly/authentication).

```
import dash
import dash_auth
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask import request

# Keep this out of source code repository - save in a file or a database
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = [
    ['hello', 'world']
]

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS
)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H2(id='show-output', children=''),
    html.Button('press to show username', id='button')

], className='container')

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='show-output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='button', component_property='n_clicks')]
)
def update_output_div(n_clicks):
    username = request.authorization['username']
    if n_clicks:
        return username
    else:
        return ''

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Surprisingly simple to integrate into an existing dash app. Worth noting that you may need to install `dash_auth`.

Comment: Based on this example its obvious that you have to put the flask.request into an callback function otherwise you get an "outside of app context" error. This example really works, thanks

Comment: Please, how to show the `username` as soon as the login is successfully completed?